# Notificação com OneSignal

Tags: android, notificação, api

Estou usando o OneSignal para notificar meus usuários Android. Só que as notificações só aparecem para os que no dia já abriram o aplicativo.
Tem algum serviço que pode ser colocado no aplicativo para sempre deixá-lo ativo e receber as notificações?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tem sim. Uso sempre este serviço.

Pela plataforma cordova, phonegap e Intel XDK e etc...

```
window.plugins.OneSignal
    .startInit("coloque aqui seu app_id ")
    .inFocusDisplaying(window.plugins.OneSignal.OSInFocusDisplayOption.None)
    .handleNotificationReceived(function(jsonMessage){
        // Coloque aqui as funçoes de retorno da notificação
    })
    .handleNotificationOpened(function(){           
       // Coloque aqui as funçoes de retorno para click da notificação
    })
    .endInit();         
    window.plugins.OneSignal.getIds(function(ids) {
        // Pegando e registrando id do usuario de cada aparelho
        // Chave de autenticação de envio e retorno
        windows.localStorage.setItem('idsAutoPush', ids.userId);
    });
```

Comment: Obrigado. Sou Designer e programo por ser autodidata.

Comment: Esta resposta resolveu o problema @AlbertoBezerra? Caso positivo, poderia marcá-la como resposta aceita, usando o botão ✓?